# Stop automatic bluetooth pairing

Tags: bluetooth

Whenever I disconnect my laptop from my bluetooth speakers manually, it pairs back to them about 5 seconds later without asking me. How do I disable this, without removing the speakers from the known devices list?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My bluetooth adapter functions over a usb bridge, rather than PCI. Might be important.

Comment: Have you tried to turn off Bluetooth? It's the easiest solution and also the more energy efficient (the difference is negligible but still...)